# Show that $x_n\in [0,1]$ for all $n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_{n+1}=-x_n^2+2x_n$ where $x_0=a\in]0,1[$. I'm trying to show by induction that $x_n\in[0,1]$, but it fail:

$$x_{n+1}=\underbrace{-x_n^2}_{\in[-1,0]}+\underbrace{2x_n}_{\in [0,2]}\in[-1,3]$$
but I can't do better. I also tried to use the fact the $x_n\in[0,1]\implies x_n^2\leq x_n$, but I can't conclude. Any help ?

Comment: You could differentiate to get tight bounds. Without differentiation, completing the square works well.

Comment: By completing the square, we get $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-x_n)\in[0,2]$. Can we do better ?

Comment: Can I say that $f:x\mapsto x(2-x)$ has a maximum in $x=1$ which is $f(1)=1$. Therefore, for all $x_n\in [0,1]$, we have that $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-x_n)\leq 1$ what prove the claim. Is it right ? For the positivity, the proof is also the same.

Comment: You should also say that $f(x) \geqslant 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then it's a complete proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Observe that

$$
x_{n+1} = 1-(x_n-1)^2
$$

and consider the values that can be taken on by $(x_n-1)^2$.